# Mercari says something like, "Your purchase is actually half price". But I don't think so. (Keyword: Shopping)

Tags: arithmetic

I am very sorry.
I forgot an important condition.
This campaign is to give back 50% of the points for the purchase amount ***for only one order during the period***.

---

Mercari is a well-known Japanese company. Currently, Mercari is running a campaign. This campaign is to give back 50% of the points for the purchase amount. Mercari says something like, "**Your purchase is actually half price"**.  The campaign is short, running from July 16, 2022 to September 30, 2022.

> Suppose I buy something that costs 1,000 yen.
> As a result, I get 500 points (1 point = 1 yen).
> Therefore, I can buy something for 1,500 yen for 1,000 yen.
> In other words, I have purchased the item at a 33% discount.

I think Mercari is wrong.

Am I right?[image]

Comment: Assuming that one point = one yen, then I think it's not unreasonable for them to claim a $50\%$ discount.  You pay $1,000$ yen and then they give you back $500$ yen, so the transaction only cost you $500$ yen.  Of course, you might complain that the $500$ they give back is worth less than $500$ yen since (I'm guessing here) it can only be spent at their shop.  But if this is a place you shop routinely, then I'd say the claim was fair.

Comment: In practice, yes you're right, because even *if* you earn another 250points by utilising that 500points (which seems unusual), I assume that you won't be utilising this 250points anyway, in other words, I assume that you have no plans to regularly shop there.

Comment: @ryang Ahh. $500+250+125+\dots=1000$ points. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Can you spend the 500 YEN to get back 250 YEN (and so on) ? In the limiting case, 1000 YEN gives you 1000 YEN back, which you already commented. **(A)** In case you can spend the 500 YEN but not get back 250 YEN, then it is only 33%. **(B)** The Image shows some timeline to use the cashback by September : Then you can not get back all the money and Discount is Strictly less than 50%. **(C)** The Image also seems to show maximum Points 3000 : Again, Paying 10000 YEN will only get you 13000 YEN which will be less than 33% **(D)** Marketing Campaigns are not known for Mathematical Accuracy !

Comment: Everyone, I am very sorry. I forgot an important condition. This campaign is to give back 50% of the points for the purchase amount for only one order during the period.

Comment: That was why I asked whether you can use the Points to get further Discounts ! It is "NO", hence you get **Maximum** 33% Discount. When you buy 1000 Y , get cashback 500 Y & then buy 500 Y with no cashback : total 1000 Y to get 1500 Y ~ 33% ! In case there is a 3000 Point limit to the cashback , then buy 10000 Y , get cashback 3000 Y , buy 3000 Y : total 10000 Y to get 13000 Y ~ 23% ! Buy even more & get even less Percent Discount ! Marketing Campaigns are known for HYPE !

Answer (score 2):

It is completely acceptable for the company to say that.

I read the example that you provided. Mercari says that it the discount is 50% off the **original price of the product**. I believe that the example you gave was an example of using the discount of one product on a **different product**.

To prove it, suppose that the price of one object is $x$ yen, and you also have $x$ yen in your balance.

You pay $x$ yen for the product, and you have $0$ yen left in your balance. However they give back half of the money, and thus you have $\dfrac{1}{2}x$ yen back in your balance.

This is the same as paying $\dfrac{1}{2}x$ yen, which is half of the listed price.

Now, in your example, you introduced another product worth $1500$ yen. This is different than the price of your original product, worth $1000$ yen. I believe that you misread the statement a little (not to criticize you by any means!). What I think you did was: $$\dfrac{1}{2}\div\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{3}=33\%$$

- Dgoat54